# Función sintáctica "para"

Tags: sintaxis

¿Qué clase de coordinada sería la siguiente frase?

> No tienes suficiente espacio de almacenamiento en iCloud para hacer una copia de seguridad de ese iPhone

¿Qué sería *para*?

Comment: La pregunta es sobre la coordinada o sobre la función sintáctica de "para"? Bienvenida a [Spanis.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [help], [tour] y [ask] para entender cómo funciona este sitio y poder sacarle todo el beneficio.

Comment: Serían las dos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien la terminología, la proposición que comienza con *para...* en este ejemplo no es una coordinada, sino una subordinada. Más específicamente, una subordinada adverbial impropia final, es decir, que expresa una finalidad u objetivo. Esta subordinada funciona como un complemento lógico que indica la finalidad de la acción (la acción es tener suficiente espacio, la finalidad es hacer una copia de seguridad).

Este tipo de subordinada puede usar *para* + verbo en subjuntivo, o bien *para* + infinitivo, como en este caso.

> *No tienes suficiente espacio... para **hacer** una copia de seguridad...*
>
> *No tienes suficiente espacio... para **que hagas** una copia de seguridad...*

Se puede usar el infinitivo en la subordinada sólo si los sujetos (implícitos) de la proposición principal y de la subordinada son el mismo, como en este caso (donde el sujeto implícito común es la segunda persona del singular, *tú*).

Comment: Claro, es verdad, cómo se me había olvidado... Gracias por aclararme :)